# How to render new.js.coffee.erb in app/views?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ujs

Using Rails 3.1 jquery_ujs, I have a link with :remote => true, and the controller new action responds with js and render new.js.erb which contains:

```
$('#post-form').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "form")) %>');
```

It renders the _form.html.erb partial. This works.

Now I want to use Coffeescript, but renaming new.js.erb to new.js.coffee.erb doesn't work. Does the asset pipeline only work in app/assets? What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I had this same issue using Rails 3.1.0.  Try renaming your file to just `new.js.coffee`.  It should still render erb despite not having the extension on the filename.

It's definitely confusing that view templates don't follow the same conventions as the asset pipeline.

Comment: confirmed; the partial is ERB evaluated despite missing the extension, and render is able to find the file fine.

Comment: If you agree that this is confusing you might want to chime in on this issue: https://github.com/rails/coffee-rails/issues/36

Comment: A little update. As of Rails 4, you can (and must) add the .erb extension for it to be parsed as a template by erb before coffeescript.

Comment: @IAmNaN up to Rails 4.1.9 though, view files named `action.js.coffee.erb` are not recognized as view templates

Comment: Actually even in Rails 4.2/coffee-rails 4.1.0 this extension is not recognized...

Comment: @OlivierLance: That's puzzling. My project has two .js.coffee.erb files and both are working. rails is at 4.2.0 and the coffee-rails gem is 4.1.0 too. No related initializers.

Comment: Damn. I can't get it to work!
Here's a test project: https://ide.c9.io/olance/erbcoffeetest
A remote link to the "test" action rendered using a `.js.coffee.erb` view... Rails complains it cannot find the view.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to keep the `.js.coffee.erb` extension here's a piece of code for Rails 4 to have Rails recognize the file as a valid view template:

```
# config/initializers/coffee_erb_handler.rb
ActionView::Template.register_template_handler 'coffee.erb', Coffee::Rails::TemplateHandler # without this there will be template not found error

class ActionView::PathResolver < ActionView::Resolver
  EXTRACT_METHODS = %w{extract_handler_and_format_and_variant extract_handler_and_format} # name for rails 4.1 resp. 4.0

  method_name = EXTRACT_METHODS.detect{|m| method_defined?(m) || private_method_defined?(m)}
  raise 'unknown extract method name' if method_name.nil?

  old_method_name = "old_#{method_name}"

  alias_method old_method_name, method_name
  define_method(method_name) do |path, default_formats|
    self.send(old_method_name, path.gsub(/\.js\.coffee\.erb$/, '.js.coffee'), default_formats)
  end
end
```

(This is a contribution [by cervinka on coffee-rails issue #36](https://github.com/rails/coffee-rails/issues/36#issuecomment-48191703))