# Coffee script with erb extension gives missing template error

Tags: coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-3.2, erb

I am using rails 3.2.11 and coffee rails 3.2.2.

Here I am trying to render a coffee script in a file **/app/views/my_files/create.js.coffee.erb**

Here is what my **controller code** looks like

```
class MyFilesController < ApplicationController    
  respond_to :js

  def create
  end

end
```

On hitting create action I get **missing template error**. But when I rename file **create.js.coffee.erb** to **create.js.coffee** it works fine.

I am not understanding what is the **problem with .erb extension** over .coffee, and in this case why it gives missing template error, when template is already there?

Thanks

Comment: how does this approach affect the asset pipeline with respect to minification? Is the pipeline smart enough to compile this down to javascript and minify it into your various application<goop>.js files?

Answer (score 1):

Rename your file to **create.js.coffee**

See
[How to render new.js.coffee.erb in app/views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616097/how-to-render-new-js-coffee-erb-in-app-views)

Just had the same problem...

Comment: This seems like a bug to me - certainly is inconsistent with js.coffee.erb files in the asset pipeline (which need the erb to pre-processed as embedded ruby). Also confuses rubymine

Answer (score -1):

Is there a particular reason you are trying to render coffeescript as a view rather than using it as an asset?

.erb is a ruby script file that produces an html file when compiled.
.js.coffee results in a .js file when compiled. You should be using .erb with a create.html.erb template that in turn uses your create.js.coffee.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "create" %>
```

This should be in your create.html.erb which will be called by the create method in your MyFilesController

Comment: yeah but you i guess .erb can be used for js, you can use it like "file.js.erb", so this doesn't look correct reason to me.

Comment: ah yes, my mistake on the .erb thing. But it looks like js.erb is only supposed to run as js after the controller action is completed. Using create.js.coffee.erb in the views folder may be trying to render it as a template which it is not. Have you tried using that in the asset folder instead?

Comment: It is an action response to a controller and does not belong in the assets folder.  Any solutions out there yet?