# render_to_string partial format error in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I get the below error when running the below code on a controller. Please note the `:formats=>[:json]` in the error, even though `:formats=>[:html]` is passed into render_to_string

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas? 
Actually, the code below worked fine before, not sure what changes influenced this error.
Rails version: 3.2.8

btw the template is definitely in place: loc/_search_details.html.erb

Bonus question: where can I find the api documentation showing what parameters can be passed to render_to_string and how it works?

Error:
**ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing partial loc/search_details with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.**

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { 
      @detail_str = render_to_string(:partial => 'loc/search_details', :layout => false, :formats=>[:html], :locals => {:beer_results => @beer_results})
      @list_str = render_to_string(:partial => 'loc/search_list', :layout => false,:formats=>[:html], :locals => {:beer_results => @beer_results})
      render :json => {:results => @results_hash, :result_details => @detail_str, :result_list => @list_str }

      }
  end
```

Comment: I don't think `:format` is a valid parameter to pass to `render`.

Comment: I'm not using :format, it's :formats

Comment: True. I don't think that is a valid parameter either though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339130/how-do-i-render-a-partial-of-a-different-format-in-rails/5074120#5074120) and [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4841). Since you're making a JSON request your `render_to_string` is expecting your partial to be `_search_details.json.erb`. You can either provide an additional JSON partial, rename the partial or add this to the partial `<% self.formats = [:json, :html] %>`, or alternatively, try the workaround in the accepted answer to that question.

Comment: You're wrong, the `:formats => [:html]` parameter to `render_to_string` makes it so it will look for `_search_details.html.erb` first. I've tested it myself, and it works, at least in Rails 3.2.9.

Comment: <% self.formats = [:json, :html] %> -- this one actually works

Comment: I needed both :formats => [:html] passed to render_to_string method, and <% self.formats = [:json, :html] %> in the partial to get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 4):

What if you try

```
render_to_string(:partial => 'loc/search_details.html.erb', :layout => false, :locals => {:beer_results => @beer_results})
```

Or

```
with_format("html") { render_to_string(:partial => 'loc/search_details', :layout => false, :locals => {:beer_results => @beer_results}) }
```

And add the method

```
private
def with_format(format, &block)
  old_format = @template_format
  @template_format = format
  result = block.call
  @template_format = old_format
  return result
end
```

Source: [How do I render a partial of a different format in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339130/how-do-i-render-a-partial-of-a-different-format-in-rails)

Comment: The first solution gives deprecation warning: DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing a template handler in the template name is deprecated. You can simply remove the handler name or pass render :handlers => [:erb] instead.

Comment: Did you try passing :handlers or did the second solution work for you?

Comment: passing handlers does not help, there's another deprecation warning about :formats html, if I add formats I'm back to the code I have and it doesn't work.
The second solution looks like a dirty hack :) I'll try it a bit later.

Comment: It is a dirty hack, but on the other hand what you are trying to do is also kind of dirty, so the solution fits the need ;)

Comment: "btw the template is definitely in place: loc/search_details.html.erb"
lol, I hope you made a typo there, you do know that partial filenames start with an underscore I hope :-) Because I tried your code in a blank rails app and it works fine, with correctly named partial of course.

Comment: yes, it was a typo :) fixed now. So it just works?? It still doesn't for me.. I'll try and find the problem tomorrow. thx.

Comment: Yes it just works for me, I copied your setup: format.json ... "@detail_str = render_to_string(:partial => 'home/index_details', :layout => false, :formats=>[:html], :locals => {:beer_results => 1}) ; render :json => {:result_details => @detail_str }"
And the file app/views/home/_index_details.html.erb. It renders properly for me. If you have problems make a simple rails app to test it and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone else stubmles on this, if you're rendering to a string, you just have to do the rendering outside the context of the format.json block. In your example:

```
respond_to do |format|
  @detail_str = render_to_string(:partial => 'loc/search_details', :locals => {:beer_results => @beer_results})
  @list_str = render_to_string(:partial => 'loc/search_list', :locals => {:beer_results => @beer_results})
  format.json {     
      render :json => {
        :results => @results_hash, 
        :result_details => @detail_str, 
        :result_list => @list_str 
      }

  }
end
```

In this way, you don't have to specify formats or layout is false.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass

```
:format => :html
```

Instead of

```
:formats => [:html]
```

Comment: `:formats` works in 4.2.1, while `:format` does not.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone has the same problem, here's what worked for me.

The error message I had when using `render_to_string` was exactly the same as in the question, complete with the `format` mismatch. However, it was not really the source of the problem.

The problem was that my app was i18n-ed and the locale was given in the URL. My `routes.rb` looks like this:

```
Quoties::Application.routes.draw do

  scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|pl/ do
    # all routes go here
  end

end
```

and my `application_controller.rb` looked like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :set_locale

  def default_url_options(options={})
    locale = I18n.locale
    locale = nil if locale == :en
    { locale: locale  }
  end

  def set_locale
    parsed_locale = params[:locale] || 'en'
    I18n.locale = I18n.available_locales.include?(parsed_locale.to_sym) ? parsed_locale : nil
  end
end
```

(It's a slightly tweaked version of a solution I found somewhere on the Internet.)

It worked pretty well in most places. However, it turned out to be the cause of the 'missing partial' error when I was using a path helper in the partial, say

```
<%= item_path(item) %>
```

The workaround which helped was replacing the above line with:

```
<%= item_path(item, locale: params[:locale]) %>
```

I've got no idea why `default_url_options` do not work in this case and why Rails raised such a weird exception.

`<% self.formats = [:html, :json] %>` solution suggested above only made the error message clearer, so that at least it changed to 'no route matches...' thrown at `item_path`.