# Ruby on Rails View inserting js.erb file via render

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

For including a piece of javascript that I only need on some pages, I put

```
 = javascript_tag do
   = render "inserts_js_enhanced_element.js.erb"
```

in my `haml` file.
Now I get the warning in my tests:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing a template handler in the template name is 
deprecated. You  can simply remove the handler name or pass render
:handlers => [:erb] instead.`
```

However, when I change the line to

```
   = render "inserts_js_enhanced_element.js", :handlers => [:erb]
```

I get a new warning anyway, saying

```
 DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing the format in the template name is 
 deprecated. Please pass render with :formats => [:js] instead.
```

If I do change this to

```
 = render "inserts_js_enhanced_element", :handlers => [:erb], :formats => [:js]
```

it gives me the error

```
     ActionView::Template::Error:
   Missing partial application/inserts_js_enhanced_element with {:handlers=>[:haml, :builder, :erb, :coffee], :locale=>[:de], :formats=>[:html]}.
```

Now the formats doesn't seem to have changed to `:js` and also the handlers are not only `:erb`.
How should I input a JS-ERB correctly?

UPDATE:

The js.erb file has the form

```
 <% session_val = determine_session_val_from_config %>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   //JS Code
 }
```

Comment: Can you show your inserts_js_enhanced_element.js.erb code?

Comment: @itsnikolay I added the structure, is this what you had in mind?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nice :)
I think I found the answer on my own with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/339130/1627888) SO article

```
= render(:partial => 'inserts_js_enhanced_element', :handlers => [:erb], :formats => [:js])
```

Works, and doesn't give me the Deprecation warning

Answer (score 3):

Did you try just use this?

```
= render "inserts_js_enhanced_element"
```

Comment: and is the filenamed "_inserts_js_enhanced_element.js.erb" ?

Comment: @ReubenMallaby yes, it's `_inserts_js_enhanced_element.js.erb`, in the same folder, app/view/users, as the file where I make the `render`