# can I change the format of render partial in a way which changes the format of the partial it loads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, mobile-fu

I'm trying to simplify a view from [spree](http://spreecommerce.com/) for a tablet, using [mobile-fu](https://github.com/brendanlim/mobile-fu), I copied the view I want to simplify and named it `.tablet.erb` and i also had to copy the admin layout and rename it to `.tabler.erb`, the problem is that the layout uses more partials, and those partials use some more, i'm trying to avoid having to copy all the files just to give them a different name or just plain change the render to tell it to use the html one.

Is there a way to tell it to use html format from that point on? like setting the format recursively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<% self.formats = [:mobile, :html] %>` on each view solved it

Got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6181539/1270248)