# Rails 3 form_tag with 'remote: true' goes to controller as HTML (after Balanced Payments callback?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

In my main `form_for` I have a modal with a `form_tag` that allows a user to add a new credit card to their account. This `form_tag` has `remote: true` so that the request can go to the `CardsController` as Ajax, where success renders a template that closes the modal and adds the new card info to the existing cards list on the main form.

The problem is that the request is going to the controller as HTML. There are a number of posts about this here on SO, but none have provided an answer that works for me. I'm using Google Chrome to debug, and in the 'Network' tab I see this:

[image: Chrome 'Network']

I don't understand 1) why the 'type' is 'text/html' given that I have set `remote: true` or 2) why the status is `302`, which I think is for a redirect.

One issue that may be at play is that this form is being acted upon by the Balanced Payments `balanced.js` to take cc info and generate a `balanced_card_id` that is then passed in a set of params to the controller. I'm guessing this is what the `302` is about but I'm not sure as I inherited this system and am not 100% sure how the Balanced Payment callback is working. At any rate, the path for my `form_tag` is the controller that expects an xhr request. If I use `binding.pry` at the top of the `CardsController#create` action, I see this:

[image: Network 2]

The full URL for the `balanced.js` callback request is `ttps://api.balancedpayments.com/jsonp/cards?callback` followed by a long string of characters. It has a request method of `GET` and a status code of `200`. The response looks like this:

```
{"status":201,"header":{"X-Balanced-Guru":"OHM64f3830e606b11e4ab4502a1fe53e539","Content-Type":"application\/json","x-balanced-host":"bapi-live-prod-7nf6hx-10-3-5-34","x-balanced-software-build":"1.8.39","Content-Length":154,"access-control-allow-origin":"*","access-control-allow-headers":"Content-Type","x-balanced-revision":"1.1","access-control-allow-methods":"POST, OPTIONS","X-Midlr-Version":"2","x-newrelic-app-data":"PxQFWFNXCQYTVVhWAwQDVUYdFhE1AwE2QgNWEVlbQFtcCxYxSBVbDQoZVA4IF0pcXAgEEBhSVhQAQhhQEAMCFlVAFEIIFBQCHVUIUQJUB1tdAwBTUVYLCgBSU04XCAFfSBEUAFVWB1oJW15UClsMC1JVWEMdQVUDCEVSPA=="},"body":"{\n  \"cards\": [\n    {\n      \"href\": \"\/cards\/CC34wrO6NsSYBoVyPM6mTtcC\",\n      \"id\": \"CC34wrO6NsSYBoVyPM6mTtcC\",\n      \"links\": {}\n    }\n  ],\n  \"links\": {}\n}"}
);
```

It is the `id` in that hash that the controller uses to associate the card with `current_user`. Somehow this response becomes the actual `params` hash that my controller receives, which I can see by using `binding.pry` and typing `params` in the console. I get this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"HW9/OFAdC373D5L7/yzqKMT2Its2uV31ZxlCe/vQtCU=",
 "balanced_card_id"=>"CC34wrO6NsSYBoVyPM6mTtcC",
 "action"=>"create",
 "controller"=>"money/cards"}
```

So I still don't understand why the original request to the controller is being received as HTML.

Here is the form:

```
  = form_tag(money_cards_path, id: 'new-card', remote: true) do
    .modal-header
      %button{ type: "button", class: "close", data: { dismiss: "modal" }}
        %span{ aria: { hidden: "true" }} &times;
        %span.sr-only Close
      %h4.modal-title New Credit Card
    .modal-body
      #errors
      %fieldset
        %p Enter your new credit card information below.
        .row
          .col-sm-8
            = render 'money/cards/form_fields'
    .modal-footer
      = submit_tag "Add Credit Card", class: 'btn btn-success', id: 'new-card-submit', autocomplete: "off"
      .pull-right.cancel
        =link_to 'Cancel', '#', data: { dismiss: "modal" }
```

And here is the controller:

```
class Money::CardsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @balanced_marketplace = ENV["BALANCED_MARKETPLACE"] #only if it fails and needs to render again

    respond_to do |format|
      if @card = current_user.add_card(params[:balanced_card_id])
        format.html { redirect_to money_root_path, notice: 'Your credit card has been successfully added.' }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render action: :new, alert: 'Failed to save credit card to your account. Please contact Sweeps for support.' }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Right now I'm being redirected to the `money_root_path` because of the request being formatted as HTML.

Comment: I think you should provide the format in your path, if you want it to be a js request, you will probably have to add `form_tag(money_cards_path, format: :js, id: 'new-card', remote: true)`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16997551/1197775

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have these two line on your application.js:

```
//= require vendor/jquery (your jQuery path)
//= require jquery_ujs
```

and in your gemfile add this line (just after gem 'rails', '3.x.x'):

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

after that you should execute:

```
run bundle install
```

and restart your server. It worked for me! when I have an element with :remote => true, it is sent by Ajax.