# Ruby on Rails fail when refresh page with ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Cheers! I have remote action in my rails project, smth like:

```
def foo
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {}
  end
end
```

Somewhere in view:

```
= link_to "foo", foo_path, remote: true
```

In my foo.js.erb file:

```
$('#bar').html("<%= j render(partial: 'bar') %>");
```

In my _bar.html.haml partial:

```
hello, i am bar
```

It's all okay and well-working, but it returns me `Missing template` error when I refreshing page on this route. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're mixing different formats (in this case, `erb` and `haml`), you'll need to specify the format of the partial.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339130/how-do-i-render-a-partial-of-a-different-format-in-rails) provides the answer. Instead of `render(partial: 'bar')`, use:

```
$('#bar').html("<%= j render(partial: '/path/bar.html.haml') %>");
```

Comment: That's it, can you fix the link in your answer? Thank you.

Comment: Sure, fix it to what? I don't know your root path.

Comment: [This question] link to the question.

Comment: Apologies! Just got what you meant. Updated