# Ruby On Rails Rendering Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, render, partial

Hi I am having problems with rendering a partial in a rails view.

I created a partial called `_my_header.html.erb` in the views/layouts directory.

Then in another file in a different folder in the views called `index.html.erb` I added:

```
 <% render 'layouts/my_header' %>
```

I put this inside a html tag. Anyway I am getting this error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in User#index

Showing C:/Buzzoo/Buzzoo/app/views/user/index.erb where line #2 raised:
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <html>
2:  <% render 'layouts/my_header' %>
3: 
4:  <body>
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of your partial? I'm wondering if the error is in there, the error message notwithstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ActionView::MissingTemplate in Player#index Showing
>   C:/Buzzoo/Buzzoo/app/views/player/index.mobile.erb where line #2
>   raised: Missing partial /layouts/mobile_header with {:locale=>[:en],
>   :formats=>[:mobile], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched
>   in: * "C:/Buzzoo/Buzzoo/app/views" *
>   "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/views"
>   Extracted source (around line #2): 1:  2: <%= render
>   '/layouts/mobile_header' %> 3: 4:

@user2527785

The above error specifies that there is no partials in the name of mobile_header. Are you sure you have a partial **_mobile_header.mobile.erb** in your layouts?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong ERB-tags around it, `<% %>` is for executing code, but `<%= %>` is for printing code.
So this is the correct code:

```
<%= render 'layouts/my_header' %>
```

The difference is explained here: [What is the difference between <%, <%=, <%# and -%> in ERB in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996695/rails-erb-syntax)

And the official docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html

Answer (score 1):

`<%= render 'layouts/my_header' %>` You need to use `<%= %>` instead of `<% %>`, when you want ruby code to show smth in your template.

Answer (score 1):

Just try the following code

```
<%= render '/layouts/my_header' %>
```

Comment: ActionView::MissingTemplate in Player#index

Showing C:/Buzzoo/Buzzoo/app/views/player/index.mobile.erb where line #2 raised:

Missing partial /layouts/mobile_header with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:mobile], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "C:/Buzzoo/Buzzoo/app/views"
  * "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/views"
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <html>
2:  <%= render '/layouts/mobile_header' %>
3: 
4:  <body>
5:

Comment: Please check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339130/how-do-i-render-a-partial-of-a-different-format-in-rails#answer-6181539