# Getting Format in Mailer View in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

In my Rails app, I use a method in my Mailer views for creating a link that takes a format param based on whether it's in `html` or `text` format.

```
mailer_link_to( url, link_text, format )
```

Depending on the format, it either creates an anchor `<a>` tag for html or just shows the `url` for text.

So for each Mailer method, I have two views:

```
myemail.html.erb
myemail.text.erb
```

In `myemail.html.erb`, I use `mailer_link_to( "http://ntwrkapp.com", "ntwrk", "html" )`.

In `myemail.text.erb` I use `mailer_link_to( "http://ntwrkapp.com", "ntwrk", "text" )`.

What I'm wondering is if I can determine what the format is so I'm not having to duplicate myself so much and specify `"html"` or `"text"` each time.

If I was in a normal view/controller, I would do something like `request.format` but the `request` object isn't available in the Mailer views.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Use `self.formats`.

Discovered in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6181539/293280) that each view has a `.formats` method that contains an Array of formats that will get used in partials and whatnot:

```
self.formats #=> [:text]
```

So, you can use this to manually pass the current format to the `mailer_link_to` method like so:

```
mailer_link_to( "http://ntwrkapp.com", "ntwrk", self.formats.first )
```

*And to preempt anybody saying I should just use a partial, which will automatically pass the correct format, I agree! I simplified my example for the sake of asking the question but in my actual use case I really did need to get the Mailer View's format manually. Thanks for trying to help, tho.*